# Android Studio Manifest merger error in package name

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : Package name ' ' at position AndroidManifest.xml:3:5-40 should contain at least one '.' (dot) character

package="com.example.myapplication"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Tabeeb"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".flipview"/>
        <activity android:name=".user_row" />
        <activity android:name=".Chat" />
        <activity android:name=".doclist" />
        <activity android:name=".chat_items" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Forgotpassword"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SignUp"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Login"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="www.tabeeb-app.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/tabeeb" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Well that certainly looks correct to me. Are you sure this is the manifest it is referring to? If there's a manifest merger there must be at least one more. I.e. maybe the applicationId isn't being set in your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to the module's "build.gradle" file -> "defaultConfig" -> "applicationId"
and change it's value to your root package name: "com.example.myapplication".

Comment: doesnt work. stil lthe same

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I am using the Ionic and Capacitor framework for anyone looking for this on a search. But my applicationId never contained the full package and app name, only the app name. Just started to break for some reason. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory
android:appComponentFactory="mystring"
```

needs to be added in `AndroidManifest.xml` in `<application>`. Find the detailed answer [at codegrepper](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/java/Manifest+merger+failed+androidx)

Answer (score -1):

> in your project build gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
}
```