# Attribute android:icon is not allowed here. I have this problem that i cannot fix, when i try to run my app, it doesnt let me

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, intellij-idea, flutter-dependencies

[image: This is the problem]

I cannot do anything, I can't run my app, I am new to Flutter, and I want to run my food app, but every time i try to run my app, it says:

- Package name ' ' at position AndroidManifest.xml:2:5-44 should contain at least one '.' (dot) character
  If someone could help me, that would be amazing. Thank you all for your replies.

Comment: Just Close your manifest file and reopen it, if not work share your manifest

Comment: I did, and it is still the same, are you maybe able to chat via zoom, so i can share my screen or something? @Fatimaayaa

Comment: just add screen of your manifest

Comment: @Fatimaayaa is that the androidmanifest.xml right? Sorry, i am new to programming, im still learning. :)

Comment: yes yes put screen or code

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vl1qr.png its same as this one, nothing changed :( @Fatimaayaa

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0C7KUzT @Fatimaayaa

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61213803/15106159